# Rails set has_one relation on object creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have a transaction model which has_one vehicle
transaction model belongs_to a sender which has_one vehicle.
On Transaction creation I need to set the transaction.vehicle from the seller.vehicle What is the best way to do this ?

before_save ? before_create ?

thanks a lot for your help.

transaction model

```
  class Transaction < ActiveRecord::Base

     attr_accessor :sender_id, :receiver_id, :receiver_phone_number

     belongs_to :sender, class_name: 'User'
     belongs_to :receiver, class_name: 'User'

     has_one :vehicle
     [...]
   end
```

vehicle model

```
class Vehicle < ActiveRecord::Base


  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :wallet_to_wallet, class_name: 'Transaction', :foreign_key => :vehicle_id

  [...]
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use before_create, in transaction model

```
before_create :before_create_tasks
def before_create_tasks
   self.build_vehicle
end
```